Is a least squares minimization equivalent to taking the product of the gaussians described by the data?
Suppose you have $N$ independent measurements of linear combinations of a multivariate normal vector $X$ such that measurement $D_i$ is $A^T_iX = \mu_i \pm \sigma_i$. One way to estimate the mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ of $X$ is to feed your data into a least squares minimizer.
My question is: is the log-likelihood described by $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ resulting from the least squares minimization process equivalent to the log-likelihood obtained from taking the sum of the log-likelihoods of the individual data? Or, algebraically:
$L(X) = \sum_i^N \left(\frac{D_i-A_i^TX}{\sigma_i}\right)^2 \propto (X-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (X-\mu)^T$
This appears to be true in the few cases I have tried, but it is unclear how to prove this. Does this follow directly from the maximum likelihood derivation of least squares?
